# Is there a workaround for this tabcontrol/tabitem bug

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Unless I'm mistaken (which I hope I am) there is a bug with the `TabControl` related to the visibility of `TabItems`.
Here's XAML that reproduces the bug.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabControl_bug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <sdk:TabControl>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem1"  Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock Text="TabItem1 which should not be visible" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem2">
                <TextBlock Text="TabItem2 which should be visible" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>
        </sdk:TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When you run this code, you'll see that TabItem2 is not "selected" and so the content that is displayed is

> TabItem 1 which should not be visible

Once you select the tab, then of course the TabItem2 content is displayed, and there's no way of getting back to tabItem1, but the issue is in the inital display.

If I set the `SelectedIndex` property to 1 the correct content is displayed.  Howerver I don't know in the XAML which the of the Tabs should be selected first.

What workarounds are possible for this issue.  Ideally the tabcontrol have preselected it's first visable tabitem.

Comment: Can we clear something up. We know that the default selected item is the first item (index 0).  Lets assume for the moment that none of the tab items are collapsed.  Are we still in the dark as to "which of the tabs should be selected first"?  or is the default correct?  If the default is correct then it follows that if the default is actually collapsed then the next available tab should be selected.  Since you can see in the Xaml what is collapsed we can see what the SelectedIndex should be.

Comment: If we don't know what is going to be collapsed that must be a result of code, should not that code set the SelectedIndex?

Comment: Workaround: Subscribe to the Loaded event for the TabControl, there find the first visible TabItem and mark it as selected.

Comment: @Nestor: Sounds like an answer to me, why have you posted as a comment?

Comment: NestorArturo, put that as an answer and I'd accept it, as that is what I've ended up doing.

Comment: I wrote it as a comment as it was the first thing that came to my mind and doesn't seems to be the most elegant solution :o)

Comment: @NestorArturo you may be right it's not be an "elegant" solution, but it certainly is a working solution, that's easy enough to understand.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, you're right we don't know what will be collapsed.  The visibility is a result of binding to a property to a ViewModel.  In theory I could bind the SelectedIndex to a property in the view model as well but that takes me from bad to worse.  Now my VM must know about UI layout.  I"m not a slave to the pattern, and can easily live with a couple lines of code behind, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found next solution.For your sample in MainPage constructor:

```
tabControl.SetValue(TabControl.SelectedContentProperty, null);
```

Also you can do that on Loaded event.

Unfortunately, TabControl.SelectedContent property doesn't have public setter so you can set SelectedContentProperty directly.

**EDIT:**

Behavior for this functionality:

```
public class UnselectContentBehavior : Behavior<TabControl>
{
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.SetValue(TabControl.SelectedContentProperty, null);
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        }
 }
```

Using sample:

```
       <sdk:TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem1"  Visibility="Collapsed">
                <TextBlock Text="TabItem1 which should not be visible" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>
            <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem2">
                <TextBlock Text="TabItem2 which should be visible" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </sdk:TabItem>

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <b:UnselectContentBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </sdk:TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question when trying to solve the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825622/silverlight-tabitem-visibility-not-changing/13276564#13276564). I found a reasonable solution which covers both cases. An attached property "SelectOnlyVisibleTabs" is set to true in the TabControl to correct its behavior. To change the visibility of the TabItems during runtime, a attached "Visibility" property also prevents the TabControl's misbehavior. The complete solution:

```
public static class TabControlExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property on a TabControl to correct the behavior
    /// of selecting Collapsed TabItems.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool GetSelectOnlyVisibleTabs(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSelectOnlyVisibleTabs(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectOnlyVisibleTabs", typeof(bool), typeof(TabControlExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(false, SelectOnlyVisibleTabsChanged));
    public static void SelectOnlyVisibleTabsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged += TabControl_SelectionChanged;
            CorrectSelection(tabControl);
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged -= TabControl_SelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        CorrectSelection(tabControl);
    }

    public static void CorrectSelection(TabControl tabControl)
    {
        var selected = tabControl.SelectedItem as UIElement;
        if (selected == null) return;

        // If the selected element is not suposed to be visible,
        // selects the next visible element
        if (selected.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
            tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items.OfType<UIElement>()
                .Where(e => e.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public static class TabItemExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property in a TabItem instead of the original "Visibility" to 
    /// correct the behavior of a TabControl when a TabItem's Visibility changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Visibility GetVisibility(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Visibility)obj.GetValue(VisibilityProperty);
    }
    public static void SetVisibility(DependencyObject obj, Visibility value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Visibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(TabItemExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, VisibilityChanged));

    public static void VisibilityChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        if (tabItem == null) return;

        var visibility = (Visibility)args.NewValue;
        if (tabItem.Visibility == visibility) return;

        tabItem.Visibility = visibility;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible) return;

        // Finds the tab's parent tabcontrol and corrects the selected item, 
        // if necessary.
        var tabControl = tabItem.Ancestors().OfType<TabControl>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        TabControlExtensions.CorrectSelection(tabControl);
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
<sdk:TabControl local:TabControlExtensions.SelectOnlyVisibleTabs="True">
    <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem1" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="TabItem1 which should not be visible (1)" />
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem2">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="TabItem2 which should be visible (2)" />
    </sdk:TabItem>
    <sdk:TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}"
                 Header="tabItem3"
                 local:TabItemExtensions.Visibility="{Binding MyProperty,
                                                             Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="TabItem with binded Visibility (3)" />
    </sdk:TabItem>
</sdk:TabControl>
```