# Silverlight TabItem Visibility not changing

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol, visibility, silverlight-5.0, tabitem

I have a TabControl with many TabItems binding to a ViewModel that has properties for each TabItem's Visibility.

```
<sdk:TabControl>
    <sdk:TabItem Name="Inventory" Header="Inventory" 
        Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"
        Visibility="{Binding Permissions.Inventory,
        Converter={StaticResource PermissiveVisibilityConverter}, 
            ConverterParameter='Viewer'}"
        DataContext="{Binding VM}" />

</sdk:TabControl>
```

All TabItems are defaulted to a Visibility of collapsed. But when the VM changes a TabItem to Visible it does not work until you move your mouse over the control...

Even if I set the visibility programmatically with a button it behaves the same way!

I have checked to see if the VM's properties are Notifying the UI, and they are with NotifyOnPropertyChanged. And if I bind the data to a button's visibility it works just fine...It is just the TabItems that seem to have a bug.

Is there a way to get the TabItem UI to refresh? Or a work-around for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of SL are you using? Are notifying property changed on both the Permissions property and the Inventory property?

Comment: Silverlight 5. Yes for both, and I checked to see if when I update the ViewModel if the TabItem sees the change and it does. It just does not update the UI.

Comment: Hmmmmm very strange! I know the Tab Control does have a few bugs in it, without looking myself the only thing I can suggest is to download the toolkit source code from codeplex and try to see if the tab control is handling the visibility of the tab items internally? Sorry I don't have an easy answer for you

Comment: The CodePlex Toolkit has a TabControl? O.o I was using the Built-In TabControl provided in the Silverlight SDK.

Comment: It's the same tab control but you get the sdk source code when you download the toolkit source as well.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem and I was able to overcome it using a attached "Visibility" property instead the original one. In this new property, I can pass the value to the original "Visibility" property and, in case the parent tab control's "SelectedItem" is being collapsed select the next visible tabItem.

However, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192567/is-there-a-workaround-for-this-tabcontrol-tabitem-bug), only that may not be enough if the first item is collapsed when the TabControl loads. This case had to be fixed in the TabControl itself, because tests showed when the fake "Visility" is set for the first time the TabItem does not have access to it's TabControl yet. Because of that I also used a attached property for the TabControl which corrects this issue.

The complete solution:

```
public static class TabControlExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property on a TabControl to correct the behavior
    /// of selecting Collapsed TabItems.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool GetSelectOnlyVisibleTabs(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty);
    }
    public static void SetSelectOnlyVisibleTabs(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectOnlyVisibleTabsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SelectOnlyVisibleTabs", typeof(bool), typeof(TabControlExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(false, SelectOnlyVisibleTabsChanged));
    public static void SelectOnlyVisibleTabsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged += TabControl_SelectionChanged;
            CorrectSelection(tabControl);
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl.SelectionChanged -= TabControl_SelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        CorrectSelection(tabControl);
    }

    public static void CorrectSelection(TabControl tabControl)
    {
        var selected = tabControl.SelectedItem as UIElement;
        if (selected == null) return;

        // If the selected element is not suposed to be visible,
        // selects the next visible element
        if (selected.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
            tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items.OfType<UIElement>()
                .Where(e => e.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

public static class TabItemExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this property in a TabItem instead of the original "Visibility" to 
    /// correct the behavior of a TabControl when a TabItem's Visibility changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Visibility GetVisibility(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Visibility)obj.GetValue(VisibilityProperty);
    }
    public static void SetVisibility(DependencyObject obj, Visibility value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(VisibilityProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Visibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(TabItemExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, VisibilityChanged));

    public static void VisibilityChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var tabItem = sender as TabItem;
        if (tabItem == null) return;

        var visibility = (Visibility)args.NewValue;
        if (tabItem.Visibility == visibility) return;

        tabItem.Visibility = visibility;
        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible) return;

        // Finds the tab's parent tabcontrol and corrects the selected item, 
        // if necessary.
        var tabControl = tabItem.Ancestors().OfType<TabControl>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        TabControlExtensions.CorrectSelection(tabControl);
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
<sdk:TabControl local:TabControlExtensions.SelectOnlyVisibleTabs="True">
        <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem1" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="TabItem1 which should not be visible (1)" />
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem Header="tabItem2">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="TabItem2 which should be visible (2)" />
        </sdk:TabItem>
        <sdk:TabItem DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}"
                     Header="tabItem3"
                     local:TabItemExtensions.Visibility="{Binding MyProperty,
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="TabItem with binded Visibility (3)" />
        </sdk:TabItem>
    </sdk:TabControl>
```

Comment: I have yet to test this in my project but it seems solid. Thank you for your work :)

Comment: So I just used this and had an issue with it simply not taking any effect.  The minor change that I needed to make was to add an event handler for the Loaded event of the TabControl as well.  Until it's all loaded, not all Visibility properties are set yet.

Comment: It worked thanks for the effort. But had to modify Ancestors to GetSelfAndAncestors in the VisibilityChanged method
tabItem.GetSelfAndAncestors().OfType<TabControl>().FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the xaml so that you're setting the DataContext first:

```
 <sdk:TabItem Name="Inventory" Header="Inventory" 
    Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}"
    DataContext="{Binding VM}"
    Visibility="{Binding Permissions.Inventory,
    Converter={StaticResource PermissiveVisibilityConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter='Viewer'}" />
```

I'm assuming that Permissions.Inventory is a property on your view model but since you haven't set the context at that point it seems like the binding shouldn't work.

Also, is your converter being hit if you set a breakpoint and if the getter on Permissions.Inventory being called?

Comment: I placed a button somewhere and I set it to flick the permission between collapsed and visible and it seems to work without moving the datacontext to be set first. The issue seems to only occur when the form is initializing.

Comment: If I initialize it as collapsed and then set it as visible with the button it does not work until you click another tab - then it pops visible. But the next time you set it collapsed and then re-visible it works just fine.